# Visual Studio 2013 Cordova RemoteBuild failed (Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.1&)

Tags: visual-studio, ios-simulator

Whenever I try to run my Cordova app from Visual Studio 2013 to Mac Simulator, I am facing this error "Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.1&cfg=debug 404" in Mac terminal as well in Visual Studio.

I am facing this error even if I am building/rebuilding my VS. It seems like it tries to connect to Mac machine but due to some reason it could not able to do so and shows this message/error on Mac as well in VS.

On Mac Machine I have run the command vcremote --secure false which in turn has made remote build server listening on port 3030. I have also setup Remote Agent Configuration in VS.

Because I am newbie so It getting really hard for me to figure what is going wrong here? Please advice me. Thanks..

Comment: when you try to run, on your Mac are you seeing any activity on the remote build console?

Comment: yes i see post "/build/tasks?command"  at terminal in MacOSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same error with VS2013 and posted here:

[VS2013 Cordova iOS Remotebuild Error Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&amp;vcordova=4.3.1&amp;cfg=debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644378/vs2013-cordova-ios-remotebuild-error-cannot-post-build-taskscommand-buildamp)

I solved it by upgrading to Visual Studio 2015.  Then it just worked.