# VS2013 Cordova iOS Remotebuild Error Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&amp;vcordova=4.3.1&amp;cfg=debug

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am a new member here and hope that I'm asking my question the right way.  I think my question is identical to the one posted at:

[Visual Studio 2013 Cordova RemoteBuild failed (Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.1&)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614658/visual-studio-2013-cordova-remotebuild-failed-cannot-post-build-taskscommand)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 with TACO to try to port a JavaScript app to iOS.  To make sure my setup is correct, I'm starting with a "Hello World" BlankCordovaApp template.  I have run remotebuild --secure false on my Mac mini.  I have configured VS Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Remote Agent Configuration to point at my Mac mini Host / Port.  When I build the cordova template in VS, I get the following:

```
1>Done executing task "RemoveDir". (TaskId:20)
1>Done building target "MDACleanAfterInstall" in project "BlankCordovaApp1.jsproj".: (TargetId:12)
1>Done executing task "CallTarget". (TaskId:10)
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '0' And $(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '-17') was evaluated as (-17 != '0' And -17 != '-17').
1>Done building target "InstallMDATargets" in project "BlankCordovaApp1.jsproj".: (TargetId:11)
1>Done executing task "CallTarget". (TaskId:8)
1>Done building target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project "BlankCordovaApp1.jsproj".: (TargetId:10)
1>Target "BuildMDA: (TargetId:14)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "C:\Users\XXX\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(Platform) == 'iOS' AND $(iOSRemoteBuildSecurityPIN) == 'NULL') was evaluated as (iOS == 'iOS' AND  == 'NULL').
1>Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(Platform)' == 'android' ) was evaluated as ( 'iOS' == 'android' ).
1>Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).
1>Task "ExportRemoteIosCertificates" skipped, due to false condition; ($(Platform) == 'iOS' AND $(iOSRemoteBuildSecurityPIN) != '') was evaluated as (iOS == 'iOS' AND  != '').
1>Task "MdaVsCli" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).
1>Using "MdaVsCli" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "MdaVsCli" (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:NpmInstallDir=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:Platform=iOS (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectDir=. (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:Configuration=Debug (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectName=BlankCordovaApp1 (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:Language=en-US (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:BuildServerUrl=http://192.168.0.10:3000 (TaskId:21)
1>  Task Parameter:BuildTarget=iOSEmulatoriPhone5 (TaskId:21)
1>   (TaskId:21)
```

and then

```
1>  ------ Submitting new build request to: http://192.168.0.10:3000/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.1&cfg=debug (TaskId:21)
1>MDAVSCLI : error : Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&amp;vcordova=4.3.1&amp;cfg=debug
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:21)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "BlankCordovaApp1.jsproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:14)
```

What I see in my Mac mini terminal output is

POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.1&cfg= debug **404** 118.747 ms - 72

I'm trying this for the first time and after failing to find a solution here and on the Microsoft boards, I'm hoping someone has seen this before and can help.  Thank you in advance.

Update:  Given that VS is "submitting a new build request" I am tentatively concluding that the problem is not on the VS build side but on the Mac simulator side.  I suspect that my Mac mini remotebuild agent is refusing to accept the build from VS and that my terminal output **404** code is a connection error.  Could this be a node.js or npm issue on the Mac?

Comment: Hey there - I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered issues with remote build and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: @JordanMatthiesen Sure.  Sent you email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by downloading Visual Studio 2015 and building the BlankCordovaApp in VS2015.