# cordova for visual studio 2013 update 5 wont install

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

i am installing cordova for visual studio 2013 update 5 on my laptop with windows 10 and i choose to install all but android SDK as it is taking so much time so. when the installation finished i found 2 errors  :

```
1- joyent node.js
 Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.

2- SQLite for windows
 the specified  driver is invalid
```

log file  : [enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ad31r5ywaodzha5/dd_mda_tools_20160108010549.log)

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov2NN.png)

Comment: sorry for grammar and spilling

Comment: k@kareem.Khalil, Unfortunately I don't have an answer, but I have a question. Why use visual studio 2013 when the latest version (visual studio community 2015) is available for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent too much time trying to get Cordova to work with VS2013 Update 5.  I solved the problem by upgrading to VS2015 Community.  It just works.

[VS2013 Cordova iOS Remotebuild Error Cannot POST /build/tasks?command=build&amp;vcordova=4.3.1&amp;cfg=debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644378/vs2013-cordova-ios-remotebuild-error-cannot-post-build-taskscommand-buildamp)

I agree with @DeanB_Develop

Comment: At our company we also stopped trying to fix VS2013 cordova tools and migrated to VS2015. Much better integration of the tools and the UI!  Much better installer!